# Using Edge.JS with Electron fails

Tags: node.js, electron, edgejs

I'm trying to use [Edge.JS](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) in an Electron application.
When requiring the edge module the application throws the following error:

Uncaught Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
\?\C:\myapp\node_modules\edge\lib\native\win32\x64\5.1.0\edge_nativeclr.node

Any idea of the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way I got it to work with edge-atom-shell:
> npm install --save-dev electron-prebuilt
> npm install edge-atom-shell
> cd node_modules/edge-atom-shell/
> node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2013
> HOME=~/.electron-gyp node-gyp rebuild --target=0.36.6 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell

Comment: Is this for Windows? I've got "'HOME' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error.

Comment: Thank you @Christian, git bash terminal was able to recognize this command and rebuilding a module solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `edge-atom-shell` instead which fixes all of these issues

Comment: Nice! But now it's throwing **Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\ws\ScriptSharp\src\ScriptSharpElectric\node_modules\edge-atom-shell\build\Release\edge.node**

Comment: You need to use electron-rebuild / follow the guide for using native modules in Electron

Comment: Yeah I did so but that failed too on Windows (will try on Ubuntu). Got it working using electron-edge though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late but will sure help some in future , this repo here solve this case scenario:

https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge